# I had an issue when calling 'yarn start' inside my project. What can I do to fix this?

Tags: node-modules, npm-install, yarnpkg

I was following this tutorial, [to get my codepen project up and running on GitHub Pages](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages/). It required Node, yarn and npm to be installed on my machine. So I checked the different versions installed on my computer, which are :

- npm 8.19.4
- yarn 1.22.19
- node v16.20.0

Problem is, once I called 'yarn install' inside my project folder, I had the following response (below). And I don't know how to interpret it.

```
taabti@poudlardo:\~/Documents/Repos/fcc_js_projects/previsualisateur-markdown$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ if-env NODE_ENV=production && npm run react-project:start:prod || npm run react-project:start:dev
/bin/sh: 1: if-env: not found

> previsualisateur-markdown@1.0.0 react-project:start:dev
> eslint modules && react-project start

sh: 1: eslint: not found  
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Does anybody have a clue what could solve this?

I had problem with npm on my machine before. Maybe my hardware is outdated, and then I can't do much about, or I must follow a specific process to reinstall packages the right way ? No way to know.

Comment: Is eslint in your package.json

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you don't have `eslint` in your list of dependencies.

You can add it by running the following command:

```bash
yarn add eslint -D
```

The `-D` option indicates that it will be added to your `devDependencies` in `package.json`, instead of `dependencies`.